# Drag and drop fill in blanks

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, html5-draggable

This is my drag and drop throw fill in blanks code.
But the thing is I also want if the user has inserted the wrong word at the wrong place after he/she getting point he/she wants to put a word in the right place.
in this code in that type of word removing is not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .draggable {background-color:#00ff00;margin:5px;padding:3px;}
      #div1,#div2 {display:inline-block;min-width:25px;min-height:10px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;border-bottom-width:2px;}
    </style>
    <script>
      function allowDrop(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
      }
      function drag(ev){
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
      }
      function drop(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.parentNode.replaceChild(document.getElementById(data), ev.target);
        document.getElementById(data).className = "";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="draggable" id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">drag</span>
    <span class="draggable" id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">drop</span>
    <br />
    This is a sample 
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div> and <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div> sentence.
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I added few changes here to make it dynamic, please note that I change the HTML and add CSS I will not go over these simple things, I will describe the javascript changes:

The following will loop through `<i>` tag and attache `remove` event to it:

```
document.querySelectorAll('i.cancel').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', remove);
});
```

The remove function, will create a new clone of `<i>` parent using [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode), then search for `<i>` tag and re-attach remove event to it since the [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method doesn't clone event listeners, then create a new element that will be our duplicate for `.draggable` that we replaced suing drop event, then attach all event listeners and attributes to it (class, ondrag, ondrop ... etc), this new div will be placed in back to the `toolbox` div.

```
function remove() {
  parentElement = this.parentElement.cloneNode(true);
  parentElement.querySelector("i.cancel").addEventListener("click", remove);
  parentElement.classList.add("draggable");
  document.querySelector(".toolbox").appendChild(parentElement);
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("droppable");
  div.ondragover = allowDrop;
  div.ondrop = drop;
  div.ondragover = allowDrop;

  this.parentElement.replaceWith(div);
}
```

One thing to notice here is that once you remove the dropped element it will be place in the wrong order, I will leave this to you fix ;) , Here is what I think you want:

```css
i.cancel {
  display: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

.drop-area:hover i {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.draggable {background-color:#00ff00;margin:5px;padding:3px;}
.droppable {display:inline-block;min-width:25px;min-height:10px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;border-bottom-width:2px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      
    </style>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="toolbox">
    <span class="draggable" id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">drag<i class="cancel">x</i></span>
    <span class="draggable" id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">drop <i class="cancel">x</i></span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="drop-area">
      This is a sample 
      <div class="droppable" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div> and <div class="droppable" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div> sentence.
    </div>
    <script>
      function allowDrop(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
      }
      function drag(ev){
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
      }
      function drop(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.parentNode.replaceChild(document.getElementById(data), ev.target);
        document.getElementById(data).className = "";
      }
      
      document.querySelectorAll('i.cancel').forEach(function(el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', remove);
      });
      
      function remove() {
        parentElement = this.parentElement.cloneNode(true);  parentElement.querySelector('i.cancel').addEventListener('click',remove)
        parentElement.classList.add('draggable');  document.querySelector('.toolbox').appendChild(parentElement);
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add("droppable");
        div.ondragover = allowDrop;
        div.ondrop = drop;
        div.ondragover = allowDrop;

        this.parentElement.replaceWith(div);   
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I mean, 
if the user wants to remove word after filling blanks. then how to remove it?

Comment: Hello @ROOT
Here id="drag1" & id="drag2" is necessary?

Comment: Glad to help, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer if you fine it helpful!

Comment: how can I submit the data after the user fills in the blank?